# c++ program on windows (g++). main() does not start

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, freeze

I have a c++ project formed by a main() function and a class declaration.
i'm using mingw g++ to compile my code.

The problem is that, even if compiling and linking well, when starting the program, the process freeze and shows nothing.

That's basically the main.cpp file:

```
int main() {
    printf("....\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    //Class instance;
    return 1;
}
....
class Class {...}
....
```

i commented the class instantiation to isolate the problem.

after the main function there's the class Class declaration.

To be clear, when running it from console, it freeze and doesn't show the printf string.

if it can be usefull i'm also linking sfml libraries, which are used in the Class methods.

How can i solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your class declaration above your main function.

C++ requires that anything be declared or defined before you can use it. The only exception that I know of is the classic:

```
int main void()
{
    //some code that does stuff;
    return 0;
}
```

which for all intensive purposes cannot be declared in the code before use.

Comment: sry i wrote a bad thing... the declaration is included above the main function. so that's not the problem.

Comment: Can you show us your code for more help? The problem is not with your program but exists inside the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's clearly not a compiling/linking problem, it has nothing to do with ordering of declarations.  It could be a number of things.  Without seeing Class'es definition, we don't know whether it contains static user-defined type members with constructor logic invoked during CRT initialization.  It could also be your libraries.  If you have dynamic libs loaded (shared objects under *nix, or DLLs under Windows), the process loader may not be able to find and/or load them, or resolve dependencies.  Is SFML dynamic?  The best way to troubleshoot this is in a debugger.  Get yourself an IDE and try running a debug build of your program in the debugger.

Comment: i found out that g++ compiled well even id there were some functions only available on linux... that's very strange, he should have pop and error... can this be the problem?